# Python script not detecting modules

Tags: linux, python, pip

there is this empire named tool which I am trying to run on my Debian. I don't know why, whenever I try to to run the script I get this error

> ImportError: No module named flask

but when I run `pip3 install flask` it says flask is already installed, which is right, cause I tried creating a python file in that directory and import flask in it. That file runs without giving any error. What is wrong, please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/unable-to-import-a-module-that-is-definitely-installed

Comment: I have looked at that, but the problem here is that other python files are running, only not the empire one.